# Understanding Purescript Eff Monad and do blocks

Tags: haskell, purescript

I'm trying to understand why the following does not work in Purescript. I have a feeling it can also be answered by the Haskell community, thus I've cross listed it.

The general gist is:

If I have a `do` block, can I not throw in a disposable value? In this instance, I'm trying to log something (similar to Haskell's `print`) in the middle of a series of monadic computations.

```
main = do
    a <- someAction1
    b <- someAction2
    _ <- log "here is a statement I want printed"
    someAction3 a b
```

Specifically, I have a function which takes the following (from the Halogen example template project)

```
data Query a = ToggleState a

eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query g
eval (Toggle next) = do
    H.modify (\state -> state { isOn = not state.isOn })
    _ <- log "updating the state!"
    pure next
```

In my mind, this should work like in Haskell

```
barf :: IO Int
barf = do
  _ <- print "Here I am!"
  return 5

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a <- barf
  _ <- print $ "the value is: " ++ (show a)
  print "done"
```

Specifically, the error that I get is type mismatch of the monads

> Could not match type `Eff` with type `Free` while trying to match type `Eff ( "console" :: CONSOLE | t6 )` with type `Free (HalogenFP t0 { "isOn" :: t1 | t2 } t3 t4)` ... etc...

I know purescript makes me declare the "things I'm touching in the monad" (i.e. `forall e. Eff ( a :: SOMEVAR, b :: SOMEOTHERVAR | eff ) Unit`, but I'm not sure how to do that in this case...

Comment: If this is just for debugging purposes, you might be interested in using [the `Debug.Trace` module from `purescript-debug`](https://github.com/garyb/purescript-debug) instead of dealing with propagating the effects everywhere, which is pretty burdensome for some temporary debug logging. You shouldn’t use that for anything but debugging, though, as the name would imply.

Comment: @AlexisKing This isn't for debugging, as much as wanting to be able to quickly shoot off a message. Also, I'd like to know why it's not working for my own education.

Comment: `H.modify` produces a `Free .. ..` while `log` produces a `Eff .. ..` - the error is telling you these are different types. You cannot use them in the same `do` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're working with version 0.12.0 of halogen you should be able to use `fromEff` from https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff-free/3.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Aff.Free#v:fromEff like so:

```
data Query a = ToggleState a

eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query g
eval (Toggle next) = do
    H.modify (\state -> state { isOn = not state.isOn })
    _ <- H.fromEff (log "updating the state!")
    pure next
```

This is going to get a lot nicer in upcoming versions of halogen (>= 0.13) in which `liftEff` should be enough.

The reason for why you can't just use `log` right away, is that `H.ComponentDSL` is not a type synonym for `Eff`, but for `Free` and so you can't simply mix `Eff` and `ComponentDSL` actions.

Comment: ah thank you. I left out my attempt to use liftEff as was confused why it wasn't lifting to the correct context.

Comment: However, I am still unable to successfully lift the Eff monad. I believe I need to specify the type in the annotation?? Is this a compiler thing?

Comment: you can't keep `g` fully polymorphic anymore. It's used to carry the effects used throughout your program. See https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/v0.12.0/examples/ajax/src/Main.purs for an example. You'll want to replace `ajax :: AJAX` with `console :: CONSOLE`